# Expression Error: Named Object: javax.faces.convert.IntegerConverter not found

Tags: jsf, select, richfaces, converters

Following is my code

```
<rich:select id="cycle_group" value="#{menuCycleBean.menuCycleDetailTO.menuCycleGroupId}" defaultLabel="#{msg['gobal.select.default.label']}" 
                converter="javax.faces.convert.IntegerConverter">
                <f:selectItems value="#{menuCycleBean.cycleGroupList}" var="n" itemLabel="#{n.label}" itemValue="#{n.id}" />
                </rich:select>
```

"menuCycleGroupId" is "Integer" Value and "n.id" is "String" value. I need to convert String to Integer. I am using following attribute `converter="javax.faces.convert.IntegerConverter"`, but it is giving error.

> Expression Error: Named Object: javax.faces.convert.IntegerConverter not found.

How can I use converter with `<rich:select>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `converter` attribute must point to either a concrete instance like `#{bean.converter}` or contain a string literal with the converter ID and not the fully qualified converter class name. If you click through `CONVERTER_ID` field constant in the standard converter's [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/IntegerConverter.html), then you'll [find out](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.convert.IntegerConverter.CONVERTER_ID) that it's `javax.faces.Integer` for the `IntegerConverter`.

So, this should do:

```
<rich:select ... converter="javax.faces.Integer" />
```

Comment: It works well when i submit the form but if i want to display update recod form with selected dropdown value allow user to edit then rich:select does not display any selected record.

Comment: That's a different problem which needs to be asked in a new question. I am also not familiar enough with RichFaces to give an answer on that off top of head.